# How do you simplify -log(x) -log(y)?

Tags: logarithms

I understand that:

$$\begin{align}
\log(x) + \log(y) &= \log(xy)\\
\log(x) - \log(y) &= \log\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)
\end{align}$$

But I wasn't sure how to simplify $-\log(x) -\log(y)$
Is it possible to simplify further?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note that $-\log(x) = \log(x^{-1}) = \log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.

Comment: Notice I edited your question to improve the formatting. It is strongly advised that you use Mathjax to format your questions on this site - it's like LaTeX for the web. I edited your question this time since you are new, but in future, please format the question yourself. See here for a quick guide: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Well, if you want to do shortcuts.   $-\log x -\log y = 0 - \log x - \log y =\log 1 - \log x -\log y = \log \frac 1x -\log y = \log \frac {\frac 1x}y = \log \frac 1{xy}$.  But doing shortcuts is no substitution for *thinking*.  All the rules of logs come from $\log K=m \iff e^m=K$ and so to solve for $??? = -\log x$ then $-???? = \log x$ so $e^{-???}=\frac 1{e^{????}} = x$ and $e^{?????} = \frac 1x$ so $???? =\log \frac 1x$.

Comment: Think about $(-1)(log(x)+log(y))$ and $-log(z)=log(z^{-1})=log(\frac{1}{z})$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

For any $a,b\in\mathbb R$, we have $$-a-b = - (a+b).$$

Answer (score 3):

Please think about it again after watching the hint provided by @5xum.

> 5xum (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/112884/5xum), How do you simplify -log(x) -log(y)?, URL (version: 2022-10-28): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4563409

In case if you are still confused:

$$
-\log{x}-\log{y}=\log{\frac{1}{x}}+\log{\frac{1}{y}}=\log{\frac{1}{xy}}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
-\log(x)-\log(y)&=&-(\log(x)+\log(y))\\
&=&-\log(xy)\\
&=&\log(1/xy)
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, think.

If $M = -\log x - \log y$ then $e^M = e^{-\log x - \log y}=e^{-\log x}e^{-\log y}=$

$\frac 1{e^{\log x}}\frac 1{e^{\log y}} = \frac 1x\frac 1y =\frac 1{xy}$.

And as $e^M = \frac 1{xy}$ that means $M = \log \frac 1{xy}$.

.....

None the less knowing that $-\log x = (-1)\times \log x = \log x^{-1} = \log \frac 1x$ should be a rule that should become second nature to you.

So $-\log x - \log y = \log \frac 1x + \log \frac 1y = \log \frac 1{xy}$ should become as fast for you as $5b + 3b = (5+3)b = 8b$ is.

Comment: Garboggle! @MartinR